# ASP.Net LoginStatus Logout Redirection

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

```
<asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" 
                             LogoutPageUrl="~/" onloggedout="LoginStatus1_LoggedOut" 
                             onloggingout="LoginStatus1_LoggingOut" /></li>
```

this is my LoginStatus, my problem was when I'm trying to logout, it goes to link

> /Default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fAdmin%2fDefault.aspx

and display an error

> This webpage has a redirect loop
>   The webpage at /Default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fAdmin%2fDefault.aspx has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

What will i do to avoid that redirection? Thank you in advance guys! :)

Comment: It's like your default.aspx is redirecting to Admin/Default.aspx? Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Have you return code for returnURL? Please check if URL contain logout then remove from the URL.

Try as below

```
if (Request.QueryString("ReturnURL") != null) { 

    Response.Redirect("login.aspx"); 
}
```

Comment: Where I can find it @Amit?

Answer (score 0):

I already solved my problem. Thank you to those who reply.

> I've putted a response.redirect in my login page (Page_Load).

I think that's the problem when I delete it, My problem was solved.